# Copper Thin Film Oxidation?

Tags: thin-films

So I am a clueless undergraduate student trying to get a glass substrate sputtered with a 100 to 200 nanometer copper thin film from one lab to another. I need to know how much time I have before the copper begins to oxidize, or at least how I could figure out how long it would take in room temperature.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some detail. What were the conditions of sputtering? Is this vacuum sputtering? Could you transport it under nitrogen? Why do you have to transport it at room temperature?

Comment: And how much oxidation is acceptable?

Comment: Why don't you keep it in an inert atmosphere, like argon or nitrogen if oxidation is to be minimized.